Constructing exact triangles from $A$-resolutions of spectra
We work in the $\infty$-category $\newcommand{\Sp}{\mathrm{Sp}}\Sp$ of spectra. Fix a homotopy commutative ring spectrum $A$. Let $X \in \Sp$ be any spectrum and assume we are given an $A$-resolution
$$
    0 \to X = I^{-1} \xrightarrow{\iota_{-1}} I^0 \xrightarrow{\iota_0} I^1 \xrightarrow{\iota_1} \cdots
$$
of $X$, that is a sequence of spectra as indicated where each $I^i$ is $A$-injective, i.e. a retract of $A \otimes Y$ for some $Y \in \Sp$, and such that $\iota_{i + 1} \circ \iota_i = 0$ for all $i$ and each sequence $[I^{i + 1}, J] \to [I^i, J] \to [I^{i - 1}, J]$ where $J$ is $A$-injective is an exact sequence of abelian groups. In his paper "On Relations Between Adams Spectral Sequences, with an Application to the Stable Homotopy of a Moore Space" Haynes Miller claims that an $A$-resolution like this gives rise to a sequence of exact triangles

where the maps $k$ have degree $-1$. Constructing the first of these is easy: If the triangle is to be exact, then $X^1$ should be the fibre of $j = \iota_{-1}$, which suggests that the map $k\colon I^0 \to X^1[1]$ is the canonical map in the resulting fibre sequence. I'm struggling to see what the map $j\colon X^1 \to I^1[1]$ should be, however. What I can produce is a map $X^1 \to I^1[-1]$, just by applying the universal property of the cofibre sequence in the diagram
$X^0 \to I^0 \to \Sigma X^1$" />
seeing as the left-hand triangle commutes. But this presumably not what I want: Neither is the grading correct nor have I made any use of the fact that I started with an $A$-resolution as opposed to an ordinary complex! On the other hand, I cannot seem to get a map with the right grading out of what's given.
My question is, thus: What is the map $j\colon X^1 \to I^1[1]$ (and, more generally, all the maps $j\colon X^n \to I^n[n]$, although I assume they will follow straightforwardly by induction) supposed to be, and how to obtain it from the given data?

I think there is a mistake in Haynes's paper: in the diagram involving $\Sigma^s I^s$ that you reproduce, it should instead say $\Sigma^{-s} I^s$. The basic example of all of this comes from the cofiber sequence
$$
I \to S \to A.
$$
If we tensor with $I^{\otimes s} \otimes X$, then we get
$$
I^{\otimes s+1} \otimes X \xrightarrow{i} I^{\otimes s} \otimes X \xrightarrow{j} A \otimes I^{\otimes s} \otimes X \xrightarrow{k} \Sigma I^{\otimes s+1} \otimes X \to \cdots.
$$
So let $X^s = I^{\otimes s} \otimes X$ and $I^s = \Sigma^s A \otimes I^{\otimes s} \otimes X$, or equivalently, $\Sigma^{-s} I^s = A \otimes I^{\otimes s} \otimes X$. Then we have
$$
X^{s+1} \xrightarrow{i} X^s \xrightarrow{j} \Sigma^{-s} I^s \xrightarrow{k} \Sigma X^{s+1} \to \cdots.
$$
I think this fixes your grading issue: you produce a map $X^1 \to I^1[-1]$, which agrees with what I've written.
